# QtCreator issue when compiling a basic QtWidgets Application in Linux

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt-creator, qtgui

I am getting an issue as below when running a basic QtWidgets Application without any modification.

> :-1: error: cannot find -lGL

I am using QtCreator version 3.0.0 Based on Qt 5.2.0 (GCC 4.6.1, 32 bit).

Note: QtConsole applications run without any problem

Project file looks like below

> ## -------------------------------------------------
>
> #
>
> ## Project created by QtCreator 2014-01-04T13:38:17
>
> #
>
> ## -------------------------------------------------
>
> QT       += core gui
>
> greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
>
> TARGET = second TEMPLATE = app
>
> SOURCES += main.cpp\
>           mainwindow.cpp
>
> HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
>
> FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Please show your project file.

Comment: I have updated the question with it

Comment: It would be nice if you could also provide a self-contained source code reproducing the issue. Preferably just a main.cpp.

Comment: included main.cpp and mainwindow.cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means, you do not either have an OpenGL library installed properly on your system, or the library path is wrong.

You will need to install the following package as per [documentation](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git#15e7b6ad3df43ff719f8388ab4afb1cc) on your Ubuntu box:

```
sudo apt-get intall libglu1-mesa-dev
```

Comment: does QtWidgets Apps need OpenGL? how do i install it if so

Comment: I installed QtCreator using the official installer. I am using Ubuntu 12.10 32 bit.

Comment: what would be the exact command to do it? so the issue is with OpenGL?

Comment: sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa or something like that. Look for the package with apt-cache search. It is quite surprising though that you do not have an opengl library installed into the path.

Comment: solved the issue with the following command sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev -y